# An if... else statement returns nothing

Tags: java, debugging, if-statement, irc

I have a small piece of Java code which first checks whether a parameter you've entered into IRC command exists or not before it selects which code segment to run. I am listening to commands through PircBotX and the command that is described below is a command which basically either lists all the people on a server, or all the people in a channel via the command `:? list (all)`.

```
if ( argments[1].equalsIgnoreCase( "list" ) ) {
  CyniChat.printDebug( "Listing chosen..." );
  if ( argments[2] != null && argments[2].equalsIgnoreCase( "all" ) ) {
    CyniChat.printDebug( "You've either got 'all' as parameter..." );
    CyniChat.printDebug( event.getUser().getNick()+" : "+thisChan.getName() );
    ircResponses.listOutput( event.getUser(), event.getBot(), thisChan.getName(), true );
    return;
  } else {
    CyniChat.printDebug( "Or you don't...." );
    CyniChat.printDebug( event.getUser().getNick()+" : "+thisChan.getName() );
    ircResponses.listOutput( event.getUser(), event.getBot(), thisChan.getName(), false );
    return; 
  }
}
```

Now, the odd thing about this statement is that while the first debugging statement is executed so the console outputs "Listing chosen...", that is the only thing that it outputs. There is neither of the other debug statements executed whenever I run `:? list` in IRC. Yet when I run `:? list all`, everything seems to run fine, the statements being executed as per normal and stuff.

In all probability, I've probably just made a very small logical error somewhere that I am finding impossible to spot. If anyone has any ideas on how to resolve this situation, the help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect an error is being thrown and you have a `catch` block that ignores it without printing an error.  Can you prove that that is not the case?

Comment: My guess would be the log is not "flushing".  Have you tried logging to another framework, or resorting to System.out.println()?

Comment: I agree with tieTYT. My guess is that arguments is of length 2, so arguments[2] throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, and you have a catch(Exception) {} which catches it and ignores it. Never catch Exception. And never, never ignore them. If you can't handle an exception, let it bubble. Executing the code step by step using a debugger would confirm it.

Comment: @tieTYT Well, proving the actual truth would require a very large edit that would span the page with code. Very simply, this is not encapsulated anywhere in a try/catch block. It goes from an onMessage() listener into this `if` statement. Also... the `argments[1] != null` is there in the first place to stop that if I remember how the && stuff works correctly (in that it checks the first to see if it's true before checking the second).

Comment: I'm not familiar with PircBotX, but it is some kind of framework that calls your onMessage() listener, I guess? It almost certainly has a try/catch block around calls to onMessage() listeners so that if the listener, for example, throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, it doesn't bring the whole system to a screeching halt. Remember, your code can be surrounded by a try/catch block **anywhere up the call stack**.

Comment: I'm guessing it is the try/catch block in the submitEvent method. You should check the log file. https://code.google.com/p/pircbotx/source/browse/src/main/java/org/pircbotx/hooks/managers/ThreadedListenerManager.java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you type in `:? list`, that's 2 arguments.  But if you check for the 3rd by doing `argments[2]`, this will throw an index out of bounds exception.  The reason you're not seeing the error message is you probably have a `catch` block that ignores it without printing an error.  You'll need to find this `catch` and at the very least put this inside it:

```
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

In the future, **never leave a catch block empty**.  Always log something or else you won't be able to notice when errors occur.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. A minor note though, for more immediate results and reasons, putting another try/catch around the statement was equally valuable and led me to the same point where I was able to fix my code (as opposed to looking for a try/catch which might not have been there).

Comment: @M477h3w1012 that's a valid point to make and may be worth doing short term so you can figure out the cause of your symptoms.  But be aware that you just put a band aid over a serious issue (that you have a silent catch block somewhere).  You should try to find that and fix it for the long term or else you'll get really weird errors like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if ( argments[2] != null && argments[2].equalsIgnoreCase( "all" ) ) {
    ...
}
```

with

```
if (arguments.length > 2 && argments[2] != null && argments[2].equalsIgnoreCase( "all" ) ) {
    ...
}
```

This ensures that there is a third element in the array before you try to access it.

Comment: Shouldn't that be >= 2 or > 1? Your evaluation would fail if there were only two elements. Also, a little explanation of why, would help the OP decide if the answer was valuable, cause copy-n-paste code causes more issues then it solves ;)

Comment: I will say that I used some of this code but not all of it. You do have a piece of redundant code in that if the length of the argments is more than 2, then the third argment, which we have just confirmed exists, cannot be null. Other than that... I did borrow the `arguments.length > 2` bit, thumbs up for pointing me in the right direction while the other answer gave me the reason behind it all.

Comment: @MadProgrammer:  Point take about adding some explanation.  But `>= 2` would not mean that you are only ensuring that elements are at 0 and 1.  It needs to be `>2`.

Comment: @M477h3w1012: you're wrong. An array of Strings can hold null values. `String[] s = new String[3]; System.out.println(s[0]);`

Comment: @M477h3w1012 An element in an array is just a placeholder, reserved in memory.  They can still be null so it's not enough to just check the array length, you have to check that there is something in at that index as well as checking the index is not out of bounds.

Comment: @JBNizet Only in the circumstances where you yourself are defining how large the array of strings is going to be. I agree that an array of Strings can hold null values, but not in this case where we are defining the Strings through a command fed into IRC.

Comment: @M477h3w1012 You have a point, I don't think you can pass `null` as a command argument.  It's a special case though, personally, I would add the check in case the method is ever called by anything else.  Be paranoid about this stuff.

Comment: @BanksySan Yes, you're right, confusion my parameter indexes...time for another morning coffee :P